# Getting default logs of celery

Tags: python, django, celery

I am not able to get access to default logs of celery without using terminal and using python code. Able to get it with terminal though using -f . want to get logs in a file using python script and that too the default logs which are generated by celery in stderr.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried use Celery Flower ?

It is a web interface to monitor and check queue and his tasks.

https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: flower is great for monitoring tasks and workers but it does not support logs as of now, https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/211

Answer (score -1):

If you are using **python file** than you can get logger as below. You can add file handler to `logger`.

```
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
```

And for default celery logs you can add following to your **`celery` worker run command**

```
-f LOGFILE, --logfile=LOGFILE
                    Path to log file. If no logfile is specified, stderr
                    is used.
```

Comment: I know how to get logs with command line but i need logs using some python script and that too the default ones which celery print on terminal

Comment: You could checkout [Celery daemonisation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html)